# Relationship issue with activerecord rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I am still learning Rails, I've read some books and did some hands on at codeschool.com and now I'm trying to write my first simple app from scratch.

I'm using devise for authentication, but since i still kinda suck at rails, I haven't gotten email confirmation working so currently, for testing purposes only Admin users can take actions.

Here are my models:

```
[loluser@fedora models]$ ls
admin.rb  pet.rb  user.rb
[loluser@fedora models]$ cat admin.rb 
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :pets 
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable, :validatable,
         :timeout_in => 20.minutes
end
[loluser@fedora models]$ cat pet.rb 
class pet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :admin
end
```

[loluser@fedora models]$

In my controller, I want to display Admin[1]'s pets in the index  so i have this code:

```
  class petsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
  # GET /pets
  # GET /pets.xml
  def index
    admin=Admin.find(1)
    @pets = pet.admin.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @pets }
    end
  end
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in petsController#index

undefined method `admin' for #<Class:0x7f2daa7b0258>

Rails.root: /home/loluser/dev/app2/devise_example
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/pets_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Help will be appreciated and please let me know if I need to clarify something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to @pets = admin.pets.all but now I'm getting the error

    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PetsController#index
    
    SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: pets.admin_id: SELECT "pets".* FROM "pets" WHERE ("pets".admin_id = 1)
    
    Rails.root: /home/heptagone/dev/app2/devise_example
    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

    app/controllers/pets_controller.rb:7:in `index'


I have already done the command "bundle exec rake:db migrate" so I'd thing that admin_id would already part of pets as you can see my models in my original post

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
@pets = admin.pets
```

You should take a look at the ActiveRecord Associations guide, it's pretty good: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the .all. You have the admin instance and admin has many pets right?
so just do

`@pets = admin.pets`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `@pets = admin.pets`
And for your error, which says you dont have admin_id field in the pets table
Remember.. if you want has_many association with pets from admin then you need to set admin_id in pets table